# php mysql query doesn't finish after update xampp 1.8.3-4

Tags: php, mysql, macos, xampp

I'm not sure how to even search for this problem because everything was working fine before the update.  I'm on a MAC and after updating the OS, XAMPP stopped connecting.  So I updated XAMPP also.  It's working but my script stops halfway through when it was working before with the older version.  Here's what I have:

```
$test = explode("||", $data);
//Section 1
    mysqli_autocommit($link, FALSE);
    mysqli_query($link, "INSERT INTO x...");
    if (mysqli_commit($link)) {
        $success = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM x...");
        $check = mysqli_num_rows($success);
        if ($check > 0) {
            $c = array();
            while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($success)) {
                $c = $row;
            }
            echo json_encode($c);
        }
    }
//Section 2
    foreach ($test as $item) {
        if ($item[0] == "#") {
            $query = mysqli_query($link, "INSERT INTO y...");
            if ($query) {
                $q = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT blah FROM z WHERE blah='$item'");
                $check = mysqli_num_rows($q);
                if ($check > 0) {
                    $s = mysqli_query($link, "UPDATE z...");
                }else{
                    $s = mysqli_query($link, "INSERT INTO z...");
            }
        }
    }
```

So when I run this, section one gets inserted, the echo works and then everything stops.  If I comment out section 1 and just run section 2, section 2 works and gets inserted.  Is there a reason why it stops halfway???

PS... I know my code isn't perfect, I'll switch to PDO later.  Just trying to get the functionality to work for now.

Another thing I tried doing...running the full script, I added this check:

```
foreach ($test as $item) {
        if ($item[0] == "#") {
            $query = mysqli_query($link, "INSERT INTO y...");
            $q = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM y");
            $c = mysqli_num_rows($q);
            if ($c > 0) {
                echo "more then 0";
            }
...
```

And it returns that there is more then 0 entries while my table is still empty...

Comment: have you tried restarting your mysql?

Comment: what does `if (mysqli_commit($link)) {` `$link` contain?

Comment: 1) You test whether your queries succeed, but never care fetching error messages whey they don't. 2) Make sure you've confdigured your development box to display PHP error messages; ask for help if unsure. 3) What exactly do you expect to accomplish with a switch to PDO?

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario Whenever I see other posts about databases, there is always someone suggesting to switching to PDO for safety reasons.  That was just a disclaimer.  Back to the question.  I get no errors.  I tested the two sections separately.  Even the foreach section returns the right ITEM.  But the queries don't work unless they are run as their own script

Comment: @Viscocent are you asking about $link?  That's the connection to the database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### AUTO COMMIT

so if you have 10 different queries it will be committed 10 times within the query.
if you are asking what's problem with this then take a look at this query:

```
1. UPDATE customer SET savings_account = savings_account - 200 WHERE...
2. UPDATE customer SET savings_account = savings_account + 200 WHERE...
```

so what if the second query fails? then `200` cash will still be deducted right?
that's where setting up the AUTO COMMIT to false enters and the use of transactions(if 1 query fails, the transaction will be invalid and will not be committed to the db).

```
try{
    $test = explode("||", $data);
    //Section 1
        mysqli_autocommit($link, FALSE);
        mysqli_query($link, "START TRANSACTION"); //<--- start Transaction
        mysqli_query($link, "INSERT INTO x...");
        if (mysqli_commit($link)) {
            $success = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM x...");
            $check = mysqli_num_rows($success);
            if ($check > 0) {
                $c = array();
                while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($success)) {
                    $c = $row;
                }
                echo json_encode($c);
            }
        }
    //Section 2
        foreach ($test as $item) {
            if ($item[0] == "#") {
                $query = mysqli_query($link, "INSERT INTO y...");
                if ($query) {
                    $q = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT blah FROM z WHERE blah='$item'");
                    $check = mysqli_num_rows($q);
                    if ($check > 0) {
                        $s = mysqli_query($link, "UPDATE z...");
                    }else{
                        $s = mysqli_query($link, "INSERT INTO z...");
                }
            }
        }
        mysqli_query($link, "COMMIT"); //<-- if all queries has been successfully excecuted it will all be saved in the db
}catch($e Exception){
    mysqli_query($link, "ROLLBACK"); //<-- rollback queries.
    throw new Exception("ERROR MESSAGE");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So apparently the problem was mysqli_autocommit.  Since I was using it in section one for multiple queries, I had to set it to FALSE.  I guess that messed it up in the later foreach loop so before running it I had to set it back to TRUE.  Now everything works.  Still don't know why...need to look up documentation on mysqli_autocommit.

Comment: Are you sure you want to quit using transactions?